# Strange vertical spacing with floats and parskip

Tags: spacing, koma-script, parskip

When I compile the following MWE with `lualatex` or `xelatex` I get strange vertical spaces between paragraphs on page 2 (see picture of output below).

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,parskip=full,twoside]{scrbook}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter}
\section{Section}
\blindtext
\subsection{Subsection}
\blindtext
\subsection{Subsection}
\blindtext

\blindtext

\blindtext
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsection{Subsection}

\end{document}
```

The problem does not occur when I remove the `parskip` option to the `\documentclass`. I would like to keep the `parskip` behaviour but I would like to get rid of these ugly spaces.

[image: page 2]

Comment: I just tried you're MWE in Overleaf and [it works normally](https://www.overleaf.com/read/twgmqjpxchny) with both Lua and XeLaTeX. Which TeX distro and OS are you running?

Comment: You will get the same issue without `parskip=full` if you add some more `\subsection` commands. There are no page break allowed between sectioning headings followed each other. For a twosided document `\flushbottom` is active so the space between the paragraphs is stretched to fill the page. This can be changed setting `\raggedbottom`. Then the additional white space will be at the bottom of the page.

Comment: presumably your final document will not have a block of consecutive section headings so will not have this problem. Latex never breaks after a section heading so you give it no choice but to stretch the paragraph space as you have specified the last line of the page must be at the bottom, If you add `some text here` after each heading, then break points will appear and so teh stretching will not be needed.

Comment: @GuilhermeZ.Santos I have the issue with MiKTeX on Windows and TeXLive on Linux. Do you know what Overleaf is running?

Comment: Ok, are those updated to the latest version? I'm not quite sure which does Overleaf runs and could not find out. I'd expect they have TL 2014 at least... Still I found it funny that it works there but not with your nested distro.

Comment: @GuilhermeZ.Santos The TL should be from 2016 and MiKTeX is an older install but updated regularly. I'm not sure what you meant with "nested distro" but my distro's are on two different machines. Maybe overleaf is using a heuristic for rendering the output to reduce server load?

Comment: @GuilhermeZ.Santos If you add the `twoside` option to `\documentclass` in [Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/read/tnfkmsdxkcrf) the behaviour described by me occurs.

Comment: @Benjamin, indeed it does! I also ran in my PC (win 10 with TL 2015) now and it seems to work normally and the problem also appears after adding the `twoside` option. Perhaps you should add that to the MWE to make the issue reproducible. And for the record: I have no idea how Overleaf does its compilation, the only information I found is that it uses [`latexmk`](https://www.overleaf.com/help/216-how-does-overleaf-compile-my-project)

Comment: @GuilhermeZ.Santos the standard classes use `\flushbottom` in `twoside`

Comment: There was a little bug in KOMA-Script versions 3.17 - 3.19a: Using one of these version  option `twoside` is implicitly set for `scrbook` but `\raggedbottom` is still active. This was fixed in version 3.20 and current version is 3.16. AFAIK Overleaf uses version 3.19a